# Defining function "constructability"

Tags: functions, reference-request, definition, constructive-mathematics

I have a question regarding the idea of a "constructible" function, in the sense that I can write down an expression for it.

For example, a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and its [Hamel basis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) exists (under the Axiom of Choice), but its constructability in that sense is, in general, not attainable. We can prove its existence, but not necessarily write it in a closed form. Also, I am not necessarily interested in constructible function in a [complex theory sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function).

I personally think I am simply using a poor term for defining a function that can be expressed by some mathematical expression or relation, and I agree this could lead to some ambiguity (see [constructive mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)), e.g.). Nonetheless, I was wondering if there is defined nomenclature that I could use to better phrase what I am describing. Any references would be great!

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function